# Get file names from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a problem. I want to get  list of the file names from S3 bucket in Snowflake? Is there anyway how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "list of the file names from S3 bucket in Snowflake"? What bucket? How are you using Snowflake? Please Edit your question to provide more information, including what you have tried and what problems you have experienced.

Comment: You need to create an [external stage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html) for that in Snowflake and then you can [list](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/list.html) them.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a problem. I want to get list of the file names from S3 bucket in Snowflake? Is there anyway how to do it?

Yes !

1. Create an external stage in Snowflake, which references the S3 bucket, using CREATE STAGE. For example:

```
CREATE STAGE my_s3_stage url = 's3://mybucket/myfiles/' ;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html

2. List the files with

```
LIST my_s3_stage ;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/list.html

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, then please consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick mark beside the answer, and if it has been useful then please also consider upvoting by clicking on the up arrow.